# Why Can I Not Get Data From My Device Tthrough Firebase?

Tags: android, html, firebase

My java code please see below:

```
package com.example.user.firebase;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Firebase mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Button mbuttonHigh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHigh);
    Button mbuttonLow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLow);
    final TextView mtextViewCondition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCondition);

    mRef = new Firebase("https://myfire.firebaseio.com/light/GPIO");
    mbuttonLow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mRef.setValue("0");
        }
    });

    mbuttonHigh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRef.setValue("1");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I can send "0" or "1" to my firebase. But I don't know why my device(ARM coretex M3 EVB) can't get data.

When I use HTML, my device(ARM coretex M3 EVB) can get data. My HTML code please see below:

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/light');
    function high(){
        var gpio = "1";
        myDataRef.set({
            GPIO: gpio,
        });
};

function low(){
    var gpio = "0";
    myDataRef.set({
        GPIO: gpio,
    });
};
```

Both two ways can send to firebase normally. I don't know why my device(ARM coretex M3) can not get data through java. Are java's setvale() and html's set different?

Thank you very much.
:D

Comment: Please next time also include the code that *reads* the data, since the problem is very likely a mismatch between the data structure of the write and read operations. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener to your Firebase reference.

```
this.mRef2.child("thing").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {..});
```

or add a ValueEventListener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My device is a ARM CoreTex M3 EVB.